# Stored procedure not executing correctly through entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

When I run the below stored procedure in SQL Management Studio, it runs as expected and takes around 5 minutes to complete.

```
exec [dbo].[sproc] '2016-02-01', '2016-02-29'
```

However, when running using Entity Framework it seems to takes 1 second and not actually do what it's supposed to do, even though I'm passing in the same parameters

Could this be a configuration issue?

I'm passing the connection string name into the `DbContext` constructor and the above is running in a thread due to timeouts

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart ( delegate ()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var d1 = new SqlParameter("Date_From", dateFrom);
        var d2 = new SqlParameter("Date_To", dateTo);
        int result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [dbo].[sproc] @Date_From, @Date_To", d1, d2);
    }
})).Start();
```

**-- Update --**

The Stored procedure expects a date time and although I can run it locally with a string (it will convert it to datetime), it will not run through ExecuteSqlCommand unless I pass the parameters as DateTimes. Surely if I'm passing a datetime parameter it should know which are days, months and years?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc]
(
    @Date_From  AS DATETIME,
    @Date_To    AS DATETIME
)
```

**-- Update --**

The following is being executing when checking through SQL Profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'exec [dbo].[sproc] @Date_From, @Date_To',N'@Date_From datetime,@Date_To datetime',@Date_From='2016-02-01 00:00:00',@Date_To='2016-02-29 00:00:00'
```

If I run this manually in SQL Server Manager I get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

User / Security / DB Settings?

Comment: are you able to get profiler running on the DB and see what query is being passed by EF?

Comment: @Jay It appears to be casting to an nvarchar? (I think) `@Date_From=N'29/02/2016',@Date_To=N'01/02/2016'`

Comment: @Jay If I run it on sql management it runs `exec [dbo].[sproc] '01-02-2016', '29-02-2016'`

Comment: is the sproc expecting a datetime value? try passing it as a datetime value rather than a string

Comment: @Jay Yeah, it's expecting a datetime however it doesn't seem to work if I set the SqlParameter to a DateTime object

Comment: can you add what the sproc is doing? Your to and from dates look to be the wrong way round?

Comment: what do you mean "not what it is supposed to do"? You are running it on another thread which is why you don't see it churning. The delegate returns void so there is no output. Are you saying it should have side effects in the database that are not happening? What if you take it out of the Thread (which is bad anyway, use `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync()`).

Comment: @Crowcoder threaded or not, it still doesn't work. Basically one of the first stages of the stored procedure selects between the two dates, and as no results are returned it just skips everything else, if I run it manually results are returned. The problem is the format being passed to the stored procedure, even if I pass a DateTime parameter

Comment: @iswinky are you sure you don't have your dates the wrong way round? in your comment above you show @Date_From=N'29/02/2016',@Date_To=N'01/02/2016' but your question has exec [dbo].[sproc] '2016-02-01', '2016-02-29'

Comment: @Jay I'll check....I really hope not

Comment: @Jay The order is correct, Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure only seemed to execute when the date time was formatted to ISO8601. This is achieved by calling ToString with "s" as the argument

```
var d1 = new SqlParameter("Date_From", dateFrom.ToString("s"));
var d2 = new SqlParameter("Date_To", dateTo.ToString("s"));
```

**Result**

> 2016-02-01T12:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with the date that `ToShortDateString()` produces as it's [not going to format the date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) like `2016-02-01`. It will produce a date based on the culture that it's running under, so will output something like this from the above link:

```
//       Displaying short date for en-US culture:
//       6/1/2009 (Short Date String)
```

SQL Server may not format this value (`'2016-02-01'`) correctly when using `.ToShortDateString()`, it might get the day and month the wrong way round, which could explain your unexpected results.

A quick test you can run in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT CAST('01/02/2016' AS DATE)
```

Does it produce: `2016-01-02` or `2016-02-01`?

You can also debug the application with a breakpoint on this line:

```
int result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [dbo].[sproc] @Date_From, @Date_To", d1, d2);
```

You can check the values in the paramters `d1` and `d2`, to ensure the format is as you expect.

Comment: @iswinky i suggest debugging the application as posted in my answer to check if the format sent to SQL is either `01/02/2016` or `02/01/2016`.

Comment: `@Date_From=N'29/02/2016',@Date_To=N'01/02/2016'` is what is showing in the sql profiler and in the debugger

Comment: @iswinky try passing dates in that format to your stored proc

Answer (score 0):

from your statements:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart ( delegate ()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var d1 = new SqlParameter("Date_From", dateFrom.ToShortDateString());
        var d2 = new SqlParameter("Date_To", dateTo.ToShortDateString());
        int result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [dbo].[sproc] @Date_From, @Date_To", d1, d2);
    }
})).Start();
```

and

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc]
(
    @Date_From  AS DATETIME,
    @Date_To    AS DATETIME
)
```

You should not be doing `dateFrom.ToShortDateString());` and `dateTo...` - your `dateFrom` and `dateTo` are already datetimes, as the SP requires.  You're currently passing a `string` into a `datetime` parameter.  Fix that, and you should be good I would think.

Also, this is a leap year, could you have some weird date mathing logic not taking that into account?

Comment: I've tried passing the datetime values and it still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was getting the exception,

> Error converting data type **nvarchar** to datetime.

I had to change the sql string to

```
int result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [dbo].[sproc] @Date_From = @Date_From, @Date_To = @Date_To", d1, d2);
```

For some reason when adding the `@Parameters` I needed to set them equal to the `SqlParameter` name. So `@Date_From, @Date_To = @Date_To..."`